# $a_1=\sqrt{6}$ , $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence $(a_n)$ is defined by $a_n > 0$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+a_n}$ for $n\ge1$. Show that

$1)$ the sequence $(a_n)$ is monotone increasing if $0 < a_1 < 3$

$2)$ the sequence $(a_n)$ is monotone decreasing if $a_1 > 3$

I know how to verify it by substituting values for $n$ but to prove generally, I don't know.
I know that the limit of the sequence is $3$ which is obtained by the positive root of $x^2 - x -6 =0$.

We usually use $a_{n+1} - a_n$ to check if a sequence is monotone increasing our monotone decreasing. But here, since intervals are involved, I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use induction along with the fact that $x \mapsto \sqrt{x+6}$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x+6}-x=0$ has the solution $x=3$.

Comment: Recall how the graphs of $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt x$ behave. They are equal at $x=0,1$. Using the same concept, think of how $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt{6+x}$. They are equal at $x=3$, so compare what happens when $0<x<3$ and $x>3$.

Comment: I know that the limit is 3 but I am not able to process it further @steve.

Comment: Wow. That's an intuitive way of thinking it. Thanks! What if I have to prove it analytically? @Awnon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a recursion formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205707/finding-a-recursion-formula)

Comment: @Learner "*We usually use $a_{n+1}−a_n$ to check if a sequence is monotone*" $\;-\;$ Doing that here gives $\require{cancel} a_{n+1}−a_n = \sqrt{6+a_n}-\sqrt{6+a_{n-1}}= \frac{(\cancel{6} + a_n) - (\cancel{6}+a_{n-1})}{\sqrt{6+a_n}+\sqrt{6+a_{n-1}}} = \frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{\sqrt{6+a_n}+\sqrt{6+a_{n-1}}}\,$, so $\,a_{n+1}-a_n\,$ and $\,a_n-a_{n-1}\,$ have the same sign.

Comment: Thank you, @Jean. But it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @dxiv, yes. It's says that the sequence is monotone increasing. The only problem I have is to prove that it is monotone increasing when $0 < a_1 < 3$ and monotone decreasing when $a_1 >= 3$. Is the only way to prove it is by substituting a value from that interval for $a_1$ and show it's monotone increasing or monotone decreasing or is there a general way?

Comment: The second interval is $a_1 > 3$ and not $a_1\ge3$. I'm not able to edit my previous comments

Comment: @Learner "*It's says that the sequence is monotone increasing*" $\;-\;$ No, it does not say that. What it says is that, by induction, all differences $a_{n+1}-a_n$ have the same sign as $a_2-a_1$, so the sequence is monotonic. Then it's enough to compare $a_1$ to $a_2 = \sqrt{a_1+6}$ to see whether the sequence is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Oh okay! And that's by substituting a value for $a_1$ from the interval? @dxiv

Comment: @dxiv You should transform your comments into an answer. I have mentionned your relationship in my answer which is mainly graphical (such staircase patterns should be present in all numerical analysis textbooks; only some give them).

Comment: @Learner See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2609394/291201) for a fully worked out answer to a very similar question. In this case $\,a_2\ge a_1 \iff a_1^2-a_1-6 \le 0 \iff (a_1-3)(a_1+2) \ge 0 \iff a_1 \le 3\,$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Your answer covers it nicely (+1). I also pointed the OP to a related answer of mine which works the same if they just adjust the expression under the radical to match the one here.

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to show by induction that in case 1) $0<a_n<3$ *for all* $n$ and in case 2) $a_n>3$ *for all* $n$. Now
$$
a_{n + 1}  - a_n  = \sqrt {6 + a_n }  - a_n  = \frac{{6 + a_n  - a_n^2 }}{{\sqrt {6 + a_n }  + a_n }} = \frac{{(3 - a_n )(a_n  + 2)}}{{\sqrt {6 + a_n }  + a_n }}.
$$
Taking into account my first sentence, the monotonicity properties follow readily.

Comment: Thank you, @Gary! I was looking for something like this.

Comment: [+1] Yes, it is another idea : putting in evidence polynomial $6+x-x^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$f(x):=\sqrt{6+x}$$

The proof by @dxiv is perfect with his key expression that I write under the following form:

$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}−a_n}{a_n-a_{n-1}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6+a_n}+\sqrt{6+a_{n-1}}} \color{red}{\approx \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{6+L}} = f'(L)}$$

with added terms in red, providing an approximation for large enough values of $n$. In this way, one (re)discovers the fact that the rate of convergence of an iterative sequence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ is governed by the derivative of $f$ at its limit value, here $L=3$.

I would like here to give a complementary graphical "proof without words" (in fact I have added a lot of words!).

[image]

*Fig. 1: The two curves with equations $y=f(x)$ and $y=x$ intersect in fixed point $(L,L)=(3,3)$ with two staircase patterns: ascending in red (with $a_0=0 < L$), descending in blue (with $a_0=6 > L$), both converging to fixed point.*

where the upper image is a zoom on the lower image. Fixed point iteration

$$a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$$

is materialized by staircase patterns, each step joining points which are alternately on the curve and on the bissector line:

$$\underbrace{(a_n,f(a_n)=a_{n+1})}_{\text{on the curve}} \ \ \to \ \ \underbrace{(a_{n+1},a_{n+1})}_{\text{on the biss. line}} \ \ \to \ \  \underbrace{(a_{n+1},f(a_{n+1})=a_{n+2})}_{\text{on the curve}} \ \ \to \ \ \text{etc.}$$

If one starts below (resp. above) limit point $3$, we will have an ascending (resp. descending) staircase.

**Remark:** See this answer of mine to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3071824) in a similar (but very particular) issue.

Comment: Thank you for the visuals @Jean. Really appreciate the effort 

Comment: Have you seen the first part I just wrote ?

Comment: I just saw it. Thank you for helping me connect the dots. @Jean

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n > 3$ then
$$a_n = \sqrt{a_n \cdot a_n} > \sqrt{3 a_n} = \sqrt{2 \cdot a_n + a_n} > \underbrace{\sqrt{6 + a_n}}_{= a_{n+1}} > \sqrt{6 + 3} = \sqrt{9} =3 $$
and if $0 < a_n < 3$ then
$$a_n = \sqrt{a_n \cdot a_n} < \sqrt{3 a_n} = \sqrt{2 \cdot a_n + a_n} < \underbrace{\sqrt{6 + a_n}}_{= a_{n+1}} < \sqrt{6 + 3} = \sqrt{9} =3 $$
by strict monotony of the square root (in each non-trivial step an $a_n$ is replaced by a $3$). The desired statement follows by complete induction on $n$.

Comment: I was to slow :)

Comment: Wow! So many ways to approach! Thank you @Carlo

Comment: @Learner: You are welcome!

Comment: @CarloK. +1. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a complement, this is a typical application of the fixed point theorem. One possible statement of the theorem is that if $g:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ is contractive, it has one and only one fixed point $z \in [a,b]$ and the iteration $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ converges to $z$, for any given $x_0\in [a,b]$. If $g$ is differentiable, the contractivity corresponds to the derivative being less than one in absolute value.

In this case, applying the theorem with $g(x)=\sqrt{6+x}$, for instance in the interval $[0,+\infty)$, you see  that the sequence converges for any $a_0 \ge 0$. Knowing that the sequence converges, it is easy to establish that $z = \sqrt{6+z}$, hence, $z = 3$. Furthermore, you can have error bounds like
$$
|a_n-3| \leq \frac{L^n}{1-L} |a_1-a_0|, \quad L = g'(0)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}.
$$